# TFS: How to compare changesets between two branches

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, tfs-sdk

How can I find changesets in Branch A that were not merged to branch B programmatically.
This what Merge Window does in TFS client GUI but I need to programmatically get the list of changesets.

Say I have `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace` reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the [VersionControlServer.GetMergeCandidates()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138934.aspx) method. This gets the candidates for merging between two paths.

```
public MergeCandidate[] GetMergeCandidates(
    string sourcePath,
    string targetPath,
    RecursionType recursion
)
```